# Get last date of month in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to update a column with "Last date of month" based on values from another column.

Eg:

- Column to be updated : Order Date
- Format : 3/31/2016
- Column from where to obtain value : Period
- Format : 201603

How can this be achieved?

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL Serverr 2012, you would use `eomonth()`:

If you have a column called `PeriodFormat`, then you would use:

```
select eomonth(cast(cast(PeriodFormat as varchar(255)) + '01' as date))
```

Note that SQL Server (and databases in general) store dates using an internal format.  That is how you should declare your date and datetime columns.  You can use `convert()` or `format()` to convert them to string representations on output.  But use the database support for dates and store the data properly.

Comment: Thanks a lot Gordon :)

Answer (score 0):

or

```
declare @aDate Date = getdate()
Select dateAdd(month, 1, dateAdd(day, -Day(@aDate),@aDate))
```

or

```
Select dateAdd(day, -Day(@aDate), dateAdd(month, 1, @aDate))
```